# Use `pbcopy` as path for cd command

Tags: shell, terminal, automator

I am using Automator on my Mac to set up a service that passes a selected folder to a bash shell script as arguments.
In the script I do:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    printf "%q\n" "$f" | pbcopy
done
```

if I then do:

```
echo `pbpaste`
```

I get the path to my selected folder with spaces escaped (`\`). I then wanted to use this path to `cd` into that directory and do a bunch of other stuff (creating a blank directory structure). I hoped I could just do:

```
cd `pbpaste`
```

but this doesn't work.
If I type the path manually the `cd` works so I assume the is some issue with data types or returns or something??

I'll admit I don't really know what this script actually doing and may be going about this all wrong but but if anyone can explain what's going on here and how to get it working it that would be great but even better would be a pointer to a really good resource for a complete beginner to start learning about shell scripting.
I really like the idea of getting into this a bit more but all the resources I have found are either total basics (cd, ls, pwd etc) or really high level and assume a bunch of previous knowledge.
What I'd really like is a full language reference with some actual examples like you find for the languages I am more used to (HTML/CSS/JS/AS3), if such a thing exists.

Cheers for any help :)

Comment: Any particular reason you are going out of your way to use the clipbaord, instead of a var?

Comment: No reason at all. I literally have no idea about this subject and am just grabbing things that look useful from a load of different sources. You wouldn't believe how much trial and error and different approaches have brought me to the above, very small piece of code. I'm not even completely firm on the syntax for declaring vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `%q` format, you are adding literal backslashes to the string, which the shell does not process as escape characters when you use it with `cd`.

The clipboard is useful for interprocess communication; inside a single script, it's easier to  just use variables to hold information temporarily. `f` already has the path name in it, so just use it:

```
cd "$f"
```

Notice I've quoted the expansion of `f`, so that any spaces in the path name are passed as part of the single argument to `cd`.

Comment: Cheers for this. Adding the quotes around the var sorted it and the rest that I wanted to do came pretty quick after that. Think I need to learn a bit more basic syntax but I suppose the best way is just to keep messing around with it.

Answer (score 14):

I'm agree with @chepner's answer, but for google's results sake, to cd using pbpaste you simply do:

```
cd $(pbpaste)
```

Comment: This does not work for me and leads to the same error as just doing `cd pbpaste` (Mac).